# How to add universal links with content inside Cordova app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

**I made it in Android.**

1. add new activity in Android Studio In MainActivity.java

   // Set by  in config.xml
   loadUrl(launchUrl);

Change to

```
 // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/Any_Page.html);
```

2. Save new activity with any name
3. In Android studio in upper menu - Tools - App link Assistent - Open url Mapping Editor Add URL Mapping path with new activity
   So no need any plugin.
   Now link open content in app.

But I can not make same link in Xcode for iOS app.
In Appdelegate.m I can change start page**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    self.viewController.startPage = @«My_page.html; // relative path works
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
@end
```

But I need get url path for choose my start page in Cordova.
Also second way - change start page from JavaScript in index.html

```
<script>
window.location.href = “MyPage.html”;
</script>
```

But I need url path where is my app open.
Url path on my web site same as in app.

```
/content/page1.html
/content/page2.html
```

Etc...
I need when my app open from link - show same content in app.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unmaintained plugin for universal links in Cordova.

I created a fork with some fixes a while back: https://github.com/GEDYSIntraWare/cordova-universal-links-plugin